# How do I pan the camera up programmatically so that it appears eye level to a "floor" plane?

Tags: typescript, three.js

I'm using `TrackballControls` to pan the camera up (hold d and drag down) above a floor-like plane that stretches into the horizon. This works correctly and achieves the desired perspective, but now I want to set the *initial* position of the camera so that it *starts* panned - without needing any keyboard controls.

I've tried looking at the source code for `TrackballControls` but I can't seem to recreate it's panning behavior.

I've tried variations of

`myCamera.translateZ(0.5);`

and

`myCamera.up.set(0,1,0);`

but the camera just ends up flipped on it's side or exhibits unexpected behavior (like breaking `TrackballControls` keyboard inputs). This should be simple: How can I pan (not rotate) the camera so it get's moved upward (perpendicular to my plane) so that the perspective starts at "eye level" rather than "ground level"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got you correctly.

For example, the initial position of your camera is `[0, 1.8, 10]`. When you use `THREE.TrackballControls()`, then the target is at `scene.position`, which is `[0, 0, 0]`. Thus, you can "rise" the target at the level of your camera:

```
controls.target.set( 0, 1.8, 0);
```

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 1.8, 10);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

var plane = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(10, 10, 10, 10), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: "red", wireframe: true}));
plane.geometry.rotateX(-Math.PI * .5);
scene.add(plane);

var targetPoint = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(.25, 4, 2), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: "yellow", wireframe: true}));
targetPoint.position.set(0, 1.8, 0);
scene.add(targetPoint);

controls.target.set(0, 1.8, 0); //controls.target.copy(targetPoint.position);

render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  controls.update();
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js"></script>
```

Comment: This really helps my issue, thanks a lot!